# Правильная форма прилагательного, стоящего около числительного

Tags: грамотная-речь, числительные

Три образных или образные сферы?

Например, в предложении "Выделяют три образных сферы, характерных для оратории"

Answer (score 1):

Обычно прилагательное должно согласовываться с существительным. Но есть исключения: полтора (полторы), два (две), три, четыре.

Перед существительными мужского и среднего рода прилагательное всегда стоит в родительном падеже множественного числа: «два высоких дома». Эта же форма прилагательного употребляется перед существительным женского рода в случае, если именительный падеж множественного числа у этого существительного («гóры») отличается (хотя бы лишь по ударению) от родительного падежа единственного числа («горы́»).

Если же формы одинаковы («сфе́ры» и в именительном падеже для множественной формы (красивые сфе́ры), и в родительном падеже в единственном числе (нету сфе́ры)), то обычно прилагательное стоит в именительном падеже множественного числа.

Так что, должно быть: **Выделяют три образные сферы**.

Answer (score 1):

Определение согласуется с существительным, зависящим от числительных **два, три, четыре**, в именительном или в родительном падеже в зависимости от грамматического рода самого существительного.
При существительных **женского рода** определение ставится в именительном падеже множественного числа (две большие комнаты, три дальние планеты, три новые машины).

**Выделяют три образные сферы, характерные для оратории.**
[Три цветные сферы](https://www.pressfoto.ru/image-829578)
*Астрономы сообщили об открытии системы, в которой находятся сразу три землеподобные планеты.*

Но! Если формы существительных женского рода в именительном падеже множественного числа отличаются по ударению от форм родительного падежа единственного числа (сестра — сестры́ — сёстры; звезда —звезды́ — звёзды), то определение обычно ставится в родительном падеже множественного числа: три старших сестры, три ярких звезды.

[Согласование определения с существительным, зависящим от числительных «два», «три», «четыре»](https://psyera.ru/soglasovanie-opredeleniya-s-sushchestvitelnym-zavisyashchim-ot-chislitelnyh-dva-tri-chetyre_8718.htm)